# ngFor rendering <!--component--> and nothing else? Not an empty array

Tags: angular

I'm mostly new to Angular coming from C# backend experience. I am having a hard time understanding why my *ngfor is not displaying. I'm sure it has something to do with how everything is nested but it's a little above my ability to figure out.

I am going to post what I think is the needed code but will definitely post more if needed.

I have a nested directive and the values seem to be getting passed just fine but the HTML template is not generating anything but `<!--container-->`.

Parent html template

```
 <div>
     <ul app-submenu></ul>
</div>
```

Sub menu template

```
asdsdf
{{items.length}}
<ul>

    <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"></li>

</ul>

<ng-template ngFor let-child let-i="index" [ngForOf]="(root ? item : item.items)">...</ng-template>
```

Sub menu component

```
@Component({
    selector: '[app-submenu]',
    templateUrl: './app.sub-menu.component.html'
})

export class AppSubMenuComponent {

items: MenuItem[]; //ngPrime menu component

constructor(public app: AppMainComponent, public appMenu: AppMenuComponent) {}

ngOnInit(){
    this.items = this.appMenu.model; //Breakpoint shows this is valid with expected values
    this.app; //Breakpoint shows this is valid with expected values
}
```

In the browser I see nothing of my list and in dev tools I see this. 4 is the correct length for the array that should be looping.

```
<ul app-submenu> 
   asdsdf 4 

   <ul class="ng-tns-c171-2">
      <!--container-->
   </ul>

   <!--container-->

</ul>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You have `ul` in the parent that contains another `ul` from the component. First, instead of `<ul app-submenu></ul>` do it instead like this: `<app-submenu></app-submenu>`, and in the component ts say `selector: 'app-submenu'`.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I know the answer I clearly did not provide enough information for the community to answer. I was indeed breaking the application into feature modules and my bindings broke.

I worked my way to this answer by slowly adding one thing at a time.

For example this worked.

```
{{item[0].label}}
```

Then I tried this and it worked.

```
<li>{{item[0].label</li>
```

etc until I tried this and it broke

```
<i [ngClass]='...'>
```

I then began googling and came across this and that was my answer.

https://www.freakyjolly.com/resolved-cant-bind-to-ngforof-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div/

So credit to Jolly whoever they are.